# 3x3 matrix and same minimal

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

I need to prove that, if $A, B\in \mathcal{M}_{3}(\mathbb{K})$ are similar matrix , then they have the same minimal polynomial.

I was thinking in another way, comparing with the others answers.

We know that all similar have the same characteristic polynomial. Then, if the minimal polynomial has degree 3, using Cayley Hamiton, it need to be characteristic polynomial. If the minimal has degree 2, then characteristic polynomial has a root in the field. How do i continue?

Comment: I can't use rational canonical form

Comment: Can you prove that, if $A$ and $B=P^{-1}AP$ are similar, and $p$ is any polynomial, then $p(B)=P^{-1}p(A)P$, hence $p(A)=0\iff p(B)=0$, hence the minimal-degree such polynomials for $A$ and $B$ match each other?

Comment: yess!! they are monic, p_A|p_B , p_B|p_A, so follow the result.